# Authentication with 2 different tables

Tags: authentication, laravel-4

I need to create a new "auth" config with another table and users. I have one table for the "admin" users and another table for the normal users.

But how can I create another instance of `Auth` with a different configuration?

Comment: Why do you need authentication on two tables? Put everyone in the same table and have a second table with specific fields for the admin users. Connect these two with a foreign key. This is the simplest approach.

Comment: Because the database is already working. Is designed this way. I'm porting the code to Laravel. Maybe i should do it manually?

Comment: I highly recommend you do to it manually. Won't be a lot of work. You will find it easier than authenticating on two tables.

Comment: In the perfect world, one user table would be best, but this isn't always possible. If you can move all the data to one table, that would be great. However, if you can't, it took me less than an hour to auth on two tables using Eloquent models. Look at my answer below.

Comment: In my case I need to be able to check login credentials in two different tables since I have both login for employees and for companies and they have totally diffenrent attributes and functionality on my site. So, sometimes you need to have more than one user table.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can "emulate" a new Auth class.

Laravel Auth component is basically the `Illuminate\Auth\Guard` class, and this class have some dependencies.

So, basically you have to create a new Guard class and some facades...

```
<?php 
use Illuminate\Auth\Guard as AuthGuard;

class CilentGuard extends AuthGuard
{

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'login_' . md5('ClientAuth');
    }

    public function getRecallerName()
    {
        return 'remember_' . md5('ClientAuth');
    }
}
```

... add a `ServiceProvider` to initialize this class, passing it's dependencies.

```
<?php 

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Auth\EloquentUserProvider;
use Illuminate\Hashing\BcryptHasher;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\PasswordBroker;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\DatabaseReminderRepository;
use ClientGuard;
use ClientAuth;

class ClientServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider 
{

    public function register()
    {
        $this->registerAuth();
        $this->registerReminders();
    }

    protected function registerAuth()
    {
        $this->registerClientCrypt();
        $this->registerClientProvider();
        $this->registerClientGuard();
    }

    protected function registerClientCrypt()
    {
        $this->app['client.auth.crypt'] = $this->app->share(function($app)
        {
            return new BcryptHasher;
        });
    }

    protected function registerClientProvider()
    {
        $this->app['client.auth.provider'] = $this->app->share(function($app)
        {
            return new EloquentUserProvider(
                $app['client.auth.crypt'], 
                'Client'
            );
        });
    }

    protected function registerClientGuard()
    {
        $this->app['client.auth'] = $this->app->share(function($app)
        {
            $guard = new Guard(
                $app['client.auth.provider'], 
                $app['session.store']
            );

            $guard->setCookieJar($app['cookie']);
            return $guard;
        });
    }

    protected function registerReminders()
    {
        # DatabaseReminderRepository
        $this->registerReminderDatabaseRepository();

        # PasswordBroker
        $this->app['client.reminder'] = $this->app->share(function($app)
        {
            return new PasswordBroker(
                $app['client.reminder.repository'], 
                $app['client.auth.provider'], 
                $app['redirect'], 
                $app['mailer'], 
                'emails.client.reminder' // email template for the reminder
            );
        });
    }

    protected function registerReminderDatabaseRepository()
    {
        $this->app['client.reminder.repository'] = $this->app->share(function($app)
        {
            $connection   = $app['db']->connection();
            $table        = 'client_reminders';
            $key          = $app['config']['app.key'];

            return new DatabaseReminderRepository($connection, $table, $key);
        });
    }

    public function provides()
    {
        return array(
            'client.auth', 
            'client.auth.provider', 
            'client.auth.crypt', 
            'client.reminder.repository', 
            'client.reminder', 
        );
    }
}
```

In this Service Provider, I put some example of how to create a 'new' password reminder component to.

Now you need to create two new facades, one for authentication and one for password reminders.

```
<?php 
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade;

class ClientAuth extends Facade
{

    protected static function getFacadeAccessor() 
    {
        return 'client.auth';
    }
}
```

and...

```
<?php 
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade;

class ClientPassword extends Facade
{

    protected static function getFacadeAccessor() 
    {
        return 'client.reminder';
    }
}
```

Of course, for password reminders, you need to create the table in database, in order to work. In this example, the table name should be `client_reminders`, as you can see in the `registerReminderDatabaseRepository` method in the Service Provider. The table structure is the same as the original reminders table.

After that, you can use your `ClientAuth` the same way you use the `Auth` class. And the same thing for `ClientPassword` with the `Password` class.

```
ClientAuth::gust();
ClientAuth::attempt(array('email' => $email, 'password' => $password));

ClientPassword::remind($credentials);
```

Don't forget to add your service provider to the service providers list in the `app/config/app.php` file.

**UPDATE:**

If you are using Laravel 4.1, the PasswordBroker doesn't need the `Redirect` class anymore.

```
return new PasswordBroker(
    $app['client.reminder.repository'], 
    $app['client.auth.provider'], 
    $app['mailer'], 
    'emails.client.reminder' // email template for the reminder
);
```

**UPDATE 2**

Laravel 5.2 just introduced [multi auth](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/authentication#introduction), so this is no longer needed in this version.

Comment: In this example I 'assume' you have a Client model, you should replace with your real model. Also I recommend to use some namespaces to organize this classes.

Comment: This answer in incomplete and has a couple of errors in it. You also need to make sure to add ClientServiceProvider to the list of providers in config/app.php and then run php artisan dump-autoload or it won't work.
In the registerClientGuard() function in the ServiceProvider, the line that says $guard = new Guard should say $guard = new ClientGuard.
In the last code block, the line that says ClientAuth::gust() should read ClientAuth::guest().
I tried to submit this as an edit since the code above won't work as is, but it was rejected for whatever reason.

Comment: Also, if you are running Laravel 4.0.9 or newer, you will need to remove the contents of the boot function as well as the registerAuthEvents() function. The reason for this is that getQueuedCookies() was removed in 4.0.9 so it causes an error.

Comment: @JordanPatterson can you explain how to work around with `getQueuedCookies` error?

Comment: @user1692333 Just remove this. It's no longer needed.

Answer (score 31):

While trying to solve this problem myself, I found a much simpler way. I basically created a custom ServiceProvider to replace the default Auth one, which serves as a factory class for Auth, and allows you to have multiple instances for multiple login types. I also stuck it all in a package which can be found here: https://github.com/ollieread/multiauth

It's pretty easy to use really, just replace the AuthServiceProvider in app/config/app.php with Ollieread\Multiauth\MultiauthServiceProvider, then change app/config/auth.php to look something like this:

```
return array(

    'multi' => array(
        'account' => array(
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => 'Account'
        ),
        'user' => array(
            'driver' => 'database',
            'table' => 'users'
        )
    ),

    'reminder' => array(

        'email' => 'emails.auth.reminder',

        'table' => 'password_reminders',

        'expire' => 60,

    ),

);
```

Now you can just use Auth the same way as before, but with one slight difference:

```
Auth::account()->attempt(array(
    'email'     => $attributes['email'],
    'password'  => $attributes['password'],
));
Auth::user()->attempt(array(
    'email'     => $attributes['email'],
    'password'  => $attributes['password'],
));
Auth::account()->check();
Auth::user()->check();
```

It also allows you to be logged in as multiple user types simultaneously which was a requirement for a project I was working on. Hope it helps someone other than me.

**UPDATE - 27/02/2014**

For those of you that are just coming across this answer, I've just recently added support for reminders, which can be accessed in the same factory style way.

Answer (score 12):

Ok, I had the same problem and here is how I solved it:

actually in laravel 4 you can simply change the auth configs at runtime so to do the trick you can simply do the following in your App::before filter:

```
if ($request->is('admin*'))
{
    Config::set('auth.model', 'Admin');
}
```

this will make the Auth component to use th Admin model when in admin urls. but this will lead to a new problem, because the login session key is the same if you have two users in your admins and users table with the same id you will be able to login to the admin site if you have logged in before as a regular user! so to make the two different authetications completely independent I did this trick:

```
class AdminGuard extends Guard
{
    public function getName()
    {
        return 'admin_login_'.md5(get_class($this));
    }

    public function getRecallerName()
    {
        return 'admin_remember_'.md5(get_class($this));
    }
}

Auth::extend('eloquent.admin', function()
{
    return new AdminGuard(new EloquentUserProvider(new BcryptHasher, 'Admin'), App::make('session.store'));
});
```

and change the App::before code to:

```
if ($request->is('admin*'))
{
    Config::set('auth.driver', 'eloquent.admin');
    Config::set('auth.model', 'Admin');
}
```

you can see that I made a new auth driver and rewrote some methods on the Guard class so it will generate different session keys for admin site. then I changed the driver for the admin site. good luck.

Comment: I would be interested if this route/request based methodology worked out for you. This sounds like something that I may experiment with. On a basic-use level, I don't see why something like this wouldn't work...

Comment: You can change the driver on any condition you please.

Comment: @Amir , Where you put AdminGuard class ?

Comment: @nabill. you can put it wherever you want, since you can load it with composer autoload, but since this is the only extension that I made I put it in global.php file.

Comment: @Amir where can i add the adminGuard class. in which folder i have to put the AdminGuard class?

Comment: @SamArulRaj as long as you're using composer you can put it anywhere you please and use composer to autoload it, you can also put in global.php file.

Comment: how can i logout from the second table ? Sorry for stupid question but i am new to this.

Comment: @PravinDodia based on your config Auth::logout() would log out the correct authentication.

Comment: @Amir Aug logout would logout any session irrespective of the logged in session, but this will impact only if the user is logged in as user as well as admin on the same machine with same browser, other wise this will not effect the functionality.
Please let me know if this clarify the question you have.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem yesterday, and I ended up creating a much simpler solution.

My requirements where 2 different tables in two different databases. One table was for admins, the other was for normal users. Also, each table had its own way of hashing. I ended up with the following (Code also available as a gist on Github: https://gist.github.com/Xethron/6790029)

Create a new UserProvider. I called mine MultiUserProvider.php

```
<?php

// app/libraries/MultiUserProvider.php

use Illuminate\Auth\UserProviderInterface,
    Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface,
    Illuminate\Auth\GenericUser;

class MultiUserProvider implements UserProviderInterface {

  protected $providers;

    public function __construct() {

        // This should be moved to the config later...
        // This is a list of providers that can be used, including
        // their user model, hasher class, and hasher options...
        $this->providers = array(
            'joomla' => array(
                'model' => 'JoomlaUser',
                'hasher' => 'JoomlaHasher',
                )
            'another' => array(
                'model' => 'AnotherUser',
                'hasher' => 'AnotherHasher',
                'options' => array(
                    'username' => 'empolyee_number',
                    'salt' => 'salt',
                    )
                ),
            );
    }
    /**
     * Retrieve a user by their unique identifier.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $identifier
     * @return \Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface|null
     */
    public function retrieveById($identifier)
    {
        // Returns the current provider from the session.
        // Should throw an error if there is none...
        $provider = Session::get('user.provider');

        $user = $this->createModel($this->providers[$provider]['model'])->newQuery()->find($identifier);

        if ($user){
            $user->provider = $provider;
        }

        return $user;
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve a user by the given credentials.
     *
     * @param  array  $credentials
     * @return \Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface|null
     */
    public function retrieveByCredentials(array $credentials)
    {
        // First we will add each credential element to the query as a where clause.
        // Then we can execute the query and, if we found a user, return it in a
        // Eloquent User "model" that will be utilized by the Guard instances.

        // Retrieve the provider from the $credentials array.
        // Should throw an error if there is none...
        $provider = $credentials['provider'];

        $query = $this->createModel($this->providers[$provider]['model'])->newQuery();

        foreach ($credentials as $key => $value)
        {
            if ( ! str_contains($key, 'password') && ! str_contains($key, 'provider'))
                $query->where($key, $value);
        }

        $user = $query->first();

        if ($user){
            Session::put('user.provider', $provider);
            $user->provider = $provider;
        }

        return $user;
    }

    /**
     * Validate a user against the given credentials.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface  $user
     * @param  array  $credentials
     * @return bool
     */
    public function validateCredentials(UserInterface $user, array $credentials)
    {
        $plain = $credentials['password'];

        // Retrieve the provider from the $credentials array.
        // Should throw an error if there is none...
        $provider = $credentials['provider'];

        $options = array();

        if (isset($this->providers[$provider]['options'])){
            foreach ($this->providers[$provider]['options'] as $key => $value) {
                $options[$key] = $user->$value;
            }
        }

        return $this->createModel($this->providers[$provider]['hasher'])
            ->check($plain, $user->getAuthPassword(), $options);
    }

    /**
     * Create a new instance of a class.
     *
     * @param string $name Name of the class
     * @return Class
     */
    public function createModel($name)
    {
        $class = '\\'.ltrim($name, '\\');

        return new $class;
    }

}
```

Then, I told Laravel about my UserProvider by adding the following lines to the top of my `app/start/global.php` file.

```
// app/start/global.php

// Add the following few lines to your global.php file
Auth::extend('multi', function($app) {
    $provider =  new \MultiUserProvider();

    return new \Illuminate\Auth\Guard($provider, $app['session']);
});
```

And then, I told Laravel to use my user provider instead of EloquentUserProvider in `app/config/auth.php`

```
'driver' => 'multi',
```

Now, when I authenticate, I do it like so:

```
Auth::attempt(array(
    'email' => $email,
    'password' => $password,
    'provider'=>'joomla'
    )
)
```

The class would then use the joomlaUser model, with the joomlaHasher, and no options for the hasher... If using 'another' provider, it will include options for the hasher.

This class was built for what I required but can easily be changed to suite your needs.

PS: Make sure the autoloader can find MultiUserProvider, else it won't work.

Comment: I'm going to try this, but its not better to put the new provider on 'providers' => array on config/app.php

Comment: @CarlosGoce: yes, I just haven't done it yet, although, I would imagine that config/auth.php would be a better place to put it...

Comment: If you do happen to make the required changes, I would appreciate if you could add a pull request on my gist with any updates :)

Comment: Latest update of Laravel (4.0.7) changed $app['session'] to $app['session.store']

Comment: Using this method, will Laravel allow me to be logged in as both a 'joomla' and 'another' user at the same time?

Comment: Hello Jeff, we use sub-domains to accomplish that. So, we have a clients.example.com and a admin.example.com. That way you can be logged into the clients and admin section at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Laravel 5 native auth to handle multiple user tables...

It's not difficult, please check this Gist:

https://gist.github.com/danielcoimbra/64b779b4d9e522bc3373

UPDATE: For Laravel 5, if you need a more robust solution, try this package:

https://github.com/sboo/multiauth

Daniel