# User cannot login when admin is logged in

Tags: php, session, authentication, laravel-5, multi-user

I have a problem in my project. When admin is logged in, no front end user can login in the same browser, why this happens? But when I destroy the cookies and then tries to login as user it correctly logs in.

How can I solve this?

Comment: you cannot do this, use separate browser, otherwise you have to use multiple session technique

Comment: Can you paste what you have done, your controller, middleware, views as no one can help you until you paste what you have done.

Comment: I didn't done this ever, but I read about this. here is the [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18979299/multiple-auth-sessions-in-laravel-4) I hope that might help

Comment: Thanks for providing me the link Qazi

Answer (score 0):

Any major browser will only store one session cookie for a site, but the site developer gets to choose what's in that cookie. It seems like your site is storing user information in the session cookie, which is then getting overwritten when the other tab stores different information in the same cookie.

You don't provide much detail about how your specific site operates, but here are a few general ways of approaching this problem.

1) **Use different browsers for different users**. Different browsers don't share cookies between them. If your goal is simply to test your site with multiple users, this is the way. You can also use Incognito/Private mode to log in a separate user, as this mode doesn't share cookies either.

2) **Don't use session cookies to store user information**. This is a non-starter on most websites, but if this is an internal site or strictly controlled environment, you may be able to pass user identification via the URL, POST data, or some other hidden identifier in the request.

3) **Store data in the session cookie for all currently logged in users**. Depending on the web framework, it may be possible to create a map of user -> cookieData and look up the correct one based on which user is making the request. This is an advanced technique, and I don't actually know if Laravel exposes this level of control.

Answer (score 0):

`Harshad` is covering all the aspects very well, but I can tell about a little trick a I have used when I wanted to test using different user rights (same browser). In my case, it was Windows Authentication, but it does not matter:

1) **define a flag** at user level (e.g. `SuperUser`). It can be 0 (false) or 1 (true).

2) **allow "impersonation"** - if an administrator has SuperUser flag set, he/she can change its roles/rights and see the site as if he/she is a normal user with that particular rights, but user management section is still accessible, to allow changing rights back.

3) Little changes are required in the user management section to allow `SuperUser` security implementation (i.e. section is showing if user does not have admin role, but it is marked as SuperUser)

So, you are testing as a single user, no multiple session cookies or other tricks are required. You can have one tab opened with your user profile and other(s) to do the actual testing.

**Note:** regarding the multiple browser suggestion, it is a quick solution for developers, but in corporate environment, this can be a real problem, as users (e.g. key users that have to test security) do not have access to more than one browser.