# Laravel 4 authenticate from different table without Sentry?

Tags: authentication, laravel

By default, Laravel 4 authentication feature can only be set for one table.

Now I have an admin table that needs to authenticate. This table seperates from user table. Is there any way to do it without installing Sentry?

I have tried setting more model and table with array in app/config/auth.php but it seems Laravel did not support arrays.

Edit, moved code from answer/question:

Actually no, I have tried using something like :

```
if($res = DB::select('select * from admin where email = ? and password = ?', array(Input::get('email'), Input::get('password')))) {
    echo 'success';
    //return Response::json(['admin' => Auth::admin()->toArray()], 202);
}
else {
    echo 'failed';
    //return Response::json(['flash' => 'Authentication failed'], 401);
}

in the method store() of my controller, but failed. Can anyone help me with this?
```

Comment: Do you have to use different tables to do this? Sentry only uses one table.  Why not just make a new row in you useres table that has user privileges.

Comment: i have to since the table is already there and it is currently impossible to merge those tables now without deleting all the data inside

Answer (score 0):

Never tried that, but just an idea : if you have a model as `Admin` for your admin table and have a controller (admin controller) to access this model then you can set the `auth.model` from the constructor function like

```
function __construct()
{
    Config::set('auth.model', 'Admin');
}
```

But, not sure if this is what you want and this is the right way.

**Update :** This looks like [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18785754/laravel-4-need-to-auth-with-2-different-tables?rq=1) that you may looking for.

Comment: hey thanks, in the end I just add a function in the authentication controller and use normal db sql to authenticate admin