# Laravel 4 authentication for different database table

Tags: php, authentication, laravel-4

I am developing a website with Laravel 4, where there are login for back-end cms admin user and front-end member. Both type of members are store on different tables. So, how can I use Laravel Auth for both?

Thanks.

Comment: Why not store them on the same table, and use ACL?

Comment: Because back-end admin and front-end member are totally different member type. The user information stored is totally different. That's why I don't like to mix them together.

Comment: User informations could be store in a separate table and joined to the user id. It makes things way easier

Comment: Have you looked at the answers here?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18785754/authentication-with-2-different-tables