# Laravel Auth::check doesn't work when Eloquent Model name is 'Account' not 'User'

Tags: authentication, laravel-4, eloquent

My database table for users is named 'account' (I use singular names for everything) and 'Account' is the model name for auth purposes.  I defined the table property on the model and changed config/auth.php like so:

```
class Account extends Ardent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface 
{
protected $guarded = array(
    'id',  // the key is just 'id' so should be ok
    'password'
//...
    protected $table = 'account';
//...
}
<?php # config/auth.php
return array(
    'driver' => 'eloquent',
    'model' => 'Account',
    'table' => 'account',  
//...
}
```

Then for login etc I have an AuthController:

```
class AuthController extends BaseController 
{
    public function login($params = null)
{
        if (Auth::check()) {  // always returns false?
            return Redirect::route('home.splash')->with('messaage', 'You are already logged in');
        }
        //...
        if (Auth::attempt($credentials, true)) {  // this works fine
            return Redirect::route("auth.welcome"); 
}
/...
}
```

I also have code in the header view that refs Auth::check() to display either the login or logout links, but it seems to always return false, so the login link is showing for a logged in user.  Auth::attempt does work fine to log in the user.  What am I missing?

---

EDIT 12/18/2013
Though I found 2 errors I had made that are related, neither of them fixed the problem, but here they are plus an interesting error from migrator that I think might be worth someone much smarter than me looking at.
First, my 2 related errors:

1 - in `bootstrap/start.php`, in the envt detection, I had `'testing' => array('*local*')` which was causing sessions not to be used.

2 - I had a misplaced closing `}` which was misdirecting me to a successful login page, when in fact there was not a successful login.  So in my original post, it is incorrect where I say that the attempt part was working.  It was not.

Here's the more interesting part.  I made a change to my `nnn_create_account_table` migration, to change the password to `string('password', 64)` then tried to run `migrate:refresh` and `migrate:reset` both of which gave this error:

```
“message”:”Class 'CreateUsersTable' not found”,”file”:”(...project_dir...)\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migrator.php”,”line”:301
```

So then I did a search on the whole project folder and could not find the text 'CreateUsersTable' anywhere except in some logs.  Why is Laravel doing this?  Is it a bug?
I ended up running a simple `migrate` command (without refresh or reset part of the command) and it worked, or at least, it didn't give errors at the CLI, but my code to use Auth methods still won't work.

I'm moving on, going to use this https://github.com/andrew13/Laravel-4-Bootstrap-Starter-Site starting platform and try to build my app based on it.  I will give up and go with 'Users' rather than 'Accounts' for my user table.

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18785754/authentication-with-2-different-tables. Read the post by Amir

Comment: The default User model extends Eloquent (https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/app/models/User.php#L6)

Comment: @Fractaliste- Ardent extends Eloquent and is a validation helper. [link]https://github.com/laravelbook/ardent