# Authentication from admin panel in Laravel 4

Tags: php, session, authentication, laravel, laravel-4

What I want to do is authenticating user from admin panel. I am going to use this in order to manage a user's account from admin panel. I can not use laravel authenticate function because I have users hashed password. Is it possible to reverse hashed password? Otherwise, is it possible to authenticate user from username?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please take a look at this function
http://laravel.com/docs/security#manually

Comment: This function is also using Auth class. I have two different user types. Admin and user. After logging in admin panel, administrator will manage user's account by authenticating his/her account. How can I use two different Auth class?

Comment: Why do you need them both at the same time ? I think authenticating user is not necessary, because you can manage the user's account with admin priviledges. In case this comment is boring, this is what I found: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18785754/authentication-with-2-different-tables

Comment: I think link you gave it to me will solve my problem. I am gonna try. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible in many ways:

```
Auth::loginUsingId(1); // using id 1
```

Or use this:

```
$user = User::find(1); // using id 1
Auth::login($user);
```

Or as you asked to log in using username, so you may try this:

```
$user = User::where('username', 'someUser')->first();
Auth::login($user);
```

If you know the `id` then you may use `loginUsingId($id)` method.