# Laravel Login authentication issue with different named table

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I am creating application using Laravel, I used "administrators" table to store administrators, how to login authenticate for administrators,

I did authenticate for users "users" table like this,

```
$input = Input::all();

$rules = array('email' => 'required|email', 'password' => 'required');
$v = Validator::make($input, $rules);

if ($v->fails()) {
    return Redirect::to('login')->withErrors($v);
} else {
    $user_email = $input['email'];
    $user_password = $input['password'];
    $credentials = array('email' => $user_email, 'password' => $user_password);

    if (Auth::attempt($credentials)) {
        return Redirect::to('dashboard');
    } else {
        return Redirect::to('login')
                        ->with('global', 'Please Register First');
    }
}
```

but how to use this for "administrators" table authentication.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Authentication with 2 different tables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18785754/authentication-with-2-different-tables)

Comment: Are you using a single table for all users (called administrators rather than the default of users) or are you trying to implement auth in two parts of your site (one that uses the default users stuff and another than uses administrators)?

Answer (score 0):

The below answer assumes you just need to use a different table (`administrators`) for normal Laravel auth (`users`). If the case is that you need to implement auth in two different ways for different parts of the site, then you'll need a method that allows for that. That can be achieved using Laravel's Guard system, but you're probably better off using some third-party system that is built specifically for this case.

---

By default, Laravel 4's authentication system is set up to use the Eloquent driver with a model called `User`. As such, you need to have that model available. A `User` model comes pre-installed with Laravel s it's all good. The 'problem' for you is that by default a model names `User` will be tied to a table called `users` in your database.

Luckily, Laravel's auth system is very configurable, and there are two ways to authenticate using the database by default (direct DB access or using an Eloquent model), both of which are configurable in themselves (which table, which model respectively). All of this should be found in your `app/config/auth.php` file. `driver` can be either `database` or `eloquent`, and then change either `table` or `model` depending on which driver you specify.

As such, there are three ways around your issue here:

- If you don't need to use a model, you can simply change the driver to `database` and specify the `administrators` table.
- If you'd still like to use a model:

  - If you would like to continue using the default `User` model, and refer to it as `User` in your code, you can just tell Eloquent to look at the `administrators` table for that model: add `protected $table = 'administrators';` to the `User`class definition.
  - If you'd prefer to use a model called `Administrator`, and you won't be using the `User` model, then simply rename the `User` model to `Administrator`, and change the eloquent model in your auth config to `Administrator`.

My advice would be the last of those three options as it is the best for code. You're using a model, which is probably going to be better for you overall, but you're not hacking an existing model to use a different table.