# Laravel dual authentication types

Tags: php, authentication, laravel

I am developing an application using Laravel 4, where I need to have 2 authentication types.

Type 1: Users - which are administators / back-office workers of the system.

Type 2: Customers - which are the visitors of the website who can do certain things (like purchase services) if they are authenticated.

The Type 1 Users are authenticated using username/password, so that fits nicely within the Laravel authentication model.

The Type 2 Customers will be authenticated either using OAuth style (with Google / Facebook) or manual authentication if the customer prefers. I do not want to mix the two together, so if you are authenticated as a customer I don't want the authentication filter to think you can access the admin pages, and vice-versa.

The two types will have their own tables (Users and Customers respectively). Is there a way to have a different Auth model running concurrently in some way? Or do I have to write my own thing for customers? What is the recommended approach in this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly this should set you on the right path.

You can simply set an account_level indicator in each table and wrap your admin routes in a filter that checks that the user's account_level is correct. For example:

in routes.php

```
Route::group(array('before' => 'admin_only'), function() {
    Route::get('my-admin-route', 'AdminController@adminAction');
});
```

in filters.php

```
Route::filter('admin_only', function() {
    if (!Auth::check() || Auth::user()->account_level !== Config::get('constants.ADMIN_ACCOUNT_LEVEL') {
        return App::abort(404);
    }
});
```

In order to log a user in that does not have a username and password in your system you would need to handle the OAuth connection separately and once you have a valid user you may use the `Auth::login($user)` method to get the user back into your usual application flow.

http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/security#manually

Comment: My issue is more to do with the `Auth` class. Should I develop my own Auth Driver (since I am not necessarily authenticating using username and password for Customers, but using OAuth)? How will my `Auth:check()` differentiate between the 2 authentication types? I could obviously resort to not using Auth at all for Customers and introduce a new class, but I don't want to reinvent the wheel if there is something designed for this scenario.

Comment: In that case you probably want to handle your OAuth login separately but still use the Auth model to handle user sessions. This can be done by employing the Auth::login method. After calling Auth::login($user) you can continue to use the Auth model as usual

Comment: So essentially, what you are suggesting is that I use `Auth` for my Users, but my own thing for `Customers` and I have a separate filter for the customer pages which uses my own thing rather than the `Auth`. Am I correct?

Comment: I suggest using `Auth` to manage the sessions of both `Customers` and `Admins`. You would simply have to implement your own OAuth connector/receiver and then force login the user with the `Auth::login($user)` method.

Comment: Yes, but in some way I need to differentiate between both in the filters and redirections. The `admin/login` auth filter needs to check that the user was authenticated through the right authenticator, and the same for the normal customers. I found another thread that seems to tackle this albeit a bit of a different scenario: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18785754/authentication-with-2-different-tables