# How to compare Laravel's hash password using a custom login form?

Tags: php, laravel, hash

Can you help me with this? I am building my own login form using Laravel. But I have a problem because I stored my password using Hash method and in my login form I used hash method again to compare. But I found out that the hash value is always changing.

Here's my code in routes:

```
Route::post('/admin_handle_login', function()
{

    $rules = array(
        'admin_username'    =>  'required',
        'admin_password'    =>  'required'
    );

    $validate_admin_login = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules);

    if($validate_admin_login->fails()) {

        $messages = $validate_admin_login->messages();

        Session::flash('warning_notification','Error: Incomplete details!');

        return Redirect::to('/flaxadmin')
                            ->withErrors($messages)
                            ->withInput(Input::except('admin_password'));

    } else {

        $d = array(
            Input::get('admin_username'), Hash::make(Input::get('admin_password'))
        );

        $validate_admin = DB::table('administrators')
                            ->select('username')
                            ->where('username', Input::get('admin_username'))
                            ->where('password', Hash::check('password', Input::get('admin_password')))
                            ->count();
        fp($d);
        fp($validate_admin);

    }

});
```

The result is

```
Array
(
    [0] => admin002
    [1] => $2y$10$RTwKHN9W1/unu1ZhYlNjauApJjjoNTBnE6td/AZ5jWgZEdqVav0um
)
0
```

In my database the password of admin002 is

```
$2y$10$47sSXLzh/YXN6Rf2fmljYO7lZaxfhXVSUTp5bssR2gYQ6Nw9luUH2
```

Is my code wrong? Or are there any proper way to do this? I am a begiiner in Laravel..

Comment: What you will have to do is find all users in the database with this username. Then you will have to check the password for each of the accounts.

Comment: I know that. But I used hashed function and it always changing whenever the page is reloaded or refresh. So if I use 123 as a password and in my database is 123 also but they are different hash value. That's why I can't get the exact value

Answer (score 21, accepted):

First, you cannot do it this way. Assuming `username` is unique, you should do:

```
$validate_admin = DB::table('administrators')
                            ->select('username')
                            ->where('username', Input::get('admin_username'))
                            ->first();

if ($validate_admin && Hash::check(Input::get('admin_password'), $validate_admin->password)) {
  // here you know data is valid
}
```

However you should think about rather using built-in methods than coding it yourself. You have `Auth::attempt` or `Auth::validate` if you want to login/check only user with password so there's really no need to code it yourself.

Comment: What'll happen if no user exists?

Comment: @DanielGelling I've added `$validate_admin &&` at the beginning of if statement

Comment: Ok I already used the model USER but I don't know how to change or overwrite the table inside the model USER. What I know is the Auth::validate is using the User model class. I used this in my customer account and it is working so I decided to create another login for my admin account

Comment: @Jerielle So you could probably look also at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18785754/authentication-with-2-different-tables

Answer (score 4):

Here you're checking the string 'password' with the hashed version of the input password.

So try fetching the user by their username and if you've a result you can compare the hashed version of the password, stored in the database, with the input password. Like so:

```
$user = DB::table('administrators')
        ->select('username', 'password')
        ->where('username', Input::get('admin_username');

if($user->count()) {
    $user = $user->first();
    if(Hash::check(Input::get('admin_password'), $user->password)) {
         //User has provided valid credentials :)
    }
}
```

Comment: i don't know how this answer got up votes, IF condition is wrong, it should be Hash::check(Input::get('admin_password'),$user->password)

Comment: @ayyanarpms You are correct, there is (was) a missing bracket...

Answer (score 2):

A slight improvement to [marcin-nabiałek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3593996/marcin-nabia%C5%82ek)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26648521/2732184), you can now use PHP's [**`password_verify`**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) to achieve the same

```
$user = App\User::where('email', $request->email)->first();

if($user && password_verify($request->password, $user->password)) {
   // authenticated user,
   // do something...
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This is useful code 100% laravel 6/7/8.

```php
if ($data = AddEmployee::where('name', $request->name)-first()) {
  $pass = Hash::check($request->password, $data->password);
  if ($pass) {
    echo "sucess";
  } else {
    echo "Password Not Valid";
  }
} else {
  echo "Username Not Valid" . "<br>";
}
```