# Changing default table for authentication Laravel 4

Tags: authentication, laravel, laravel-4

I am developing a package for Laravel 4 I need to add some authentication and authorization to this package, I need to use a table other than users table in this case: "admins"

The laravel application by default is looking for the table Users and check if the username and password exist there, I need my app to take advantage of default Authentication  of Laravel (which looks the users table), but I also need to keep away the data of admins from the normal users and have authentication for another table as well (in 2 different tables).

Question: 
How should I solve this issue? do I have to override the settings of auth.php file or can I extend this authentication  in my own package so it work alongside with auth of Laravel 4?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Authentication with 2 different tables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18785754/authentication-with-2-different-tables)

Answer (score 0):

To change that open app/config/auth.php

change 'table' => 'users' into 'table' => 'admins'

and also change 'model' => 'Admin'

Comment: I modified the question to make it more clear I need to different authentication one the default one for table users and one for my package which uses Admin table