# Creating multiple logins

Tags: laravel-4

I'm using Laravel 4.2 and I'm trying to create a site that has 2 logins. One is the admin login and the other is the students login which I'm struggling with.

The issue I'm having is that even though the email and password is correct it still says "not successful".

I've tried looking it up but I don't see any tutorials on having multiple logins.

I'm also using Ollieread’s Multiple Authentication

My StudentsController.php

```
public function studentDoLogin()
{

    if(Auth::student()->attempt(['email' => Input::get('email'), 'password' => Input::get('password')])){
        echo "You were successful";
    }else{
        echo "Not successful";
    }


}
```

auth.php

```
return array(

'multi' => array(
    'student' => array(
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => 'Student'
    ),
    'user' => array(
        'driver' => 'database',
        'table' => 'users'
    )
),

'reminder' => array(

    'email' => 'emails.auth.reminder',

    'table' => 'password_reminders',

    'expire' => 60,

),

);
```

If there is anything else that I need to show please let me know.

Comment: Is Auth::student()->attempt($data) working? As far as I know that must be Auth::attempt($data). I might miss something here.

Comment: @CalinBlaga - Where did you get the data from? if I did something like `$data = array(
    'email' => Input::get('email'),
    'password' => Input::get('password')
   );

  if(Auth::student()->attempt($data)){
   echo "yep";
  }else{
   echo "no";
  }` Then I get an error saying "Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Auth\EloquentUserProvider::validateCredentials()"

Comment: I said that you can't do Auth::something() but, as far as I know it's Auth::attempt(). Update: maybe you will find this useful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18785754/authentication-with-2-different-tables